# Learning Python coming from PHP

Tags: php, python

My dynamic language experience is solely PHP. I want to learn Python now to broaden my career opportunities and just because I like programming. :)

When learning Java, I used a site (lost the URL/real name now), something like "Java for PHP developers" that had all on one side of the page the PHP code, and on the other side the Java code to do the same thing. Is there a website like that for Python?

Any other recommendations/advice?

Thanks

Comment: No way, I wanted to ask the *exact same question* today :)

Comment: @Pekka - Great minds think alike (or "dumb-asses don't differ"). :D

Comment: @Coronatus True! I think we'll have to leave it open which one applies :D

Comment: I think we need a new close reason: Post contains phrase "kthxbai". ;)

Comment: You'd probably do better to learn Python without referring to PHP (such as with the Python tutorial, http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). PHP is improving, but it's still well behind other languages in expressiveness and features. You don't want to get stuck using PHP idioms in Python (or Java, for that matter).

Comment: @outis mentioning the language you come from is important because the learning path for an experienced web developer is a different one than for somebody who knows no programming at all, or comes from the "classical" application development world for example. Plus, while I see what you mean (I come from the Pascal/Delphi world originally, and boy, *that* was a stern master compared to PHP!), it's unfair to say PHP is that much "behind other languages", looking at version 5 and even more, 5.3. It's definitely improving and already a great, reliable workhorse for developing web applications.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The OP's question is simple enough, but as @Pekka mentioned (or hijacked), this could be a much deeper question (requiring a more substantial answer). Yes, Python's syntax is easy enough to learn without a book, but like any other language, it still takes quite a bit of time to master.

The suggest of Dive Into Python is valid, although the Python 3 version is only for newbies with no baggage (meaning no existing Python code, no libraries/dependencies that haven't been ported to Python 3 yet, etc.). Sadly Mark has removed most of his online content. Here is one archive of his Python 3 book: http://www.diveintopython3.net ... it is a very good high-level introduction to the language by immersing you into coding bits right away.

If you are looking for something slightly more comprehensive, I wrote [Core Python Programming](http://corepython.com) specifically targeted towards programmers already literate in another high-level language like Java, C/C++, PHP, Ruby, etc., who need to learn Python as quickly and as in-depth as possible... it's more like a "deep dive" than a "quick dive." For pure reference books that you can pull off the shelf as necessary, I would suggest either Beazley's [Python Essential Reference](http://dabeaz.com/per.html) or Martelli's [Python in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100469/)... both are excellent, altho Alex's book is not rev'd to the latest Python releases yet. I'm sure he's working on it tho. ;-)

[UPDATED Jun 2015] Back on hijacked topic, there are several options when it comes to developing web apps on Python, the most popular currently is [Django](http://djangoproject.com). That is a full-stack web framework that is the closest thing that Python has to Ruby on Rails. It has templating, an ORM, can run on various core components (RDBMSs, webservers, JavaScript libraries, etc.), comes with an amazing admin interface, and a whole lot more. For even more functionality, also take a look at [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com). An alternative to Django is [Pyramid](http://pylonsproject.org). Instead of a single monolithic framework, Pyramid/Pylons act more like glue, tying together best-of-breed components, i.e., [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org) for templating, [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for the ORM, [MochiKit](http://www.mochikit.com/) as the JS library, etc. The 3rd option, primarily for high-trafficked, low-latency, scalable apps is [Google App Engine](http://cloud.google.com/appengine). You write your apps in Python (or Java, PHP, or Go) and upload to Google to run your app on their infrastructure. Most of the development will be similar to developing web apps on a standard LAMP stack, *except* for the datastore. Based on Google's [BigTable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html), it's a non-relational distributed object database, so the largest hurdle is overcoming thinking in a relational DB way; also released independently as [Google Cloud Datastore](http://cloud.google.com/datastore). There's also a relational MySQL-compatible alternative called [Google Cloud SQL](http://cloud.google.com/sql) should you prefer that instead of a NoSQL solution. BigTable is also available as a standalone technology from App Engine and available as [Google Cloud Bigtable](http://cloud.google.com/bigtable). That enough options for you?!? :-)

Hope this helps!

ps. If you're looking for an upcoming [comprehensive 3-day course in Python](http://cyberwebconsulting.com), talk to me. :-)

Comment: Yet another great example of pythonist nice.

Comment: The "Core Python Programming" link is dead, is there an up-to-date version?

Comment: Try corepython.com instead; see reviews at amzn.com/0132269937

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure such a thing exists but Python is generally an easy language to learn.  Python documentation is generally very clear and easy to follow.  From the Python interpreter you can also use the dir() and help() methods to view methods, attributes and documentation which makes it easy to explore what options are available to you in Python.

A few examples of differences between PHP and Python:

Python:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for a in x:
    print a
print "Loop is over"
```

PHP:

```
$x = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
foreach($x as $a) {
    echo $a.PHP_EOL
}
echo 'Loop is over'.PHP_EOL;
```

As you can see, Python does away with using '{' and '}' and instead uses indentation to see when the for-loop is complete.

Python:

```
x = {'spam':'hello', 'eggs':'world'}
if x.get('spam'):
    print x['spam']
```

PHP:

```
$x = array('hello'=>'spam', 'world'=>'eggs');
if array_key_exists('hello', $x) {
    echo $x['hello'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Not to hijack @Coronatus's question but what also would be interesting is tutorials on higher-level stuff like how to organize a scalable web application, how to build a basic class framework etc. etc. essentially, how do you do "xyz" in Python when you already know what it is, and how it's done in PHP?  the basic syntax, I'm sure, is easy to learn when you come from another language.

Comment: A lot of concepts transfer right over between PHP and Python.  A lot of initial confusion comes from the fact that indentation is important in Python.  Also, looping and if statements are a bit different.  I'll edit my answer above to include some examples.

Answer (score 6):

This basic intro with PHP references is a place to start

[IBM Developer Works:Python Basics for PHP Programmers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-pythonbasics/)