# Beginning python for the web

Tags: php, python

I'm looking for a nice tutorial or framework for developing Python written web applications.

I've done lots in PHP, but very little in Python or Ruby and figured I'd start with the first one alphabetically.

Comment: "Python VS PHP, Differences?" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464001/python-vs-php-differences) has good answers on how a PHP dev can move to Python.

Comment: here's another one similar to @matthew's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561362

Comment: Shouldn't be you be starting with 4D then? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). It's one of the more popular Python web frameworks out there and arguably the easiest to use for simple projects.

Comment: Agreed, also recommend starting at the excellent tutorial: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I tried that but I got some weird errors when adding a mysql database. Perhaps it's time to retry?

Comment: if u get an error, post it here, and we'll try to sort it out

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what level you want to work at, there are various ways to get started. At the most basic level, there is the [WSGI specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/), which is kind of like Python's version of the CGI specification, and writing a WSGI application is a lot like writing a CGI script. There are various higher-level frameworks that you could work with, of which Django (mentioned in Dav's answer) is probably the most popular.

Comment: For someone coming from a background of a lot of PHP, I wouldn't recommend plain WSGI/CGI since this would just make Python look less useful than PHP itself. Django is a much better advice, because it really shows how Python's abstraction mechanisms can be employed to make this task nice and friendly

Comment: `s/less useful/more powerful/`... at least, that's the impression I had, coming to Python from a PHP and Java background. Some people will have a better time starting from the basics. It's not automatically better to recommend that someone pick up Django first because it's an enormously complex system.

Comment: I did a lot of Java several years ago. I fear most of it (the JFrame / Panel stuff) has leaked out of my head.

Comment: for someone who has done a lot of php as the OP has claimed, I think WSGI is a fine suggestion. Django isn't always the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Turbogears](http://www.turbogears.org/) is also a fantastic python web framework (or more) and it is lighter then Django in my opinion (what is not so relevant ;) ).
It has good documentation and tutorials. Anyway if you are familiar with MVC concept both of them a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I just started Python for web myself. I also came from a PHP background and felt that PHP is fine when it comes to making regular stuff like forums, blogs and stuff like that. Sadly though I didn't like PHP when it came to create more complex systems.

I looked at a few of the different frameworks out there and came to the conclusion if I want to use a Framework that applies as much to web as to client and server side programming Turbogears2 would suit med best.

Seems like one of the "newer" frameworks and looks like they got a solid community that will keep they going for years to come.

Oh, lol this post sounds like and ad. Sorry ;)

Anyway, I like to use webpages that you can work with the hardware on the server, which means CGI/WSGI or just Turbogears :)